# How can I dump the data which has been added recently?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

On a daily basis I will download the data from mongodb and make a backup. I use the command

```
mongodump -h $MONGODB_SERVICE_HOST -o /opp/rot/llc/ttc -u 'admin' \
  -p $MONGODB_ADMIN_PASSWORD
```

So in this dump every day the total db is downloading. It is consuming so much space.

I want to know is there a way where we can download (dump) only the extra added data from the last dump we have made and add it to the main data?